# Twitter login using TwitterOAuth

Tags: asp.net, twitter-oauth

I want to login twitter using asp.net with 'TwitterOAuth'.I have added reference to TwitterOAuth.Default.aspx page contains login button

```
<a   href='http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?<%=GetUrlParamters()%>'>Login with Twitter</a>
```

and default.aspx.cs contains

```
namespace TwitterOAuth.Web.UI
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void OnBtnTwitterLoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected string GetUrlParamters()
        {
            ITwitterOAuthManager oAuthManager = new TwitterOAuthManager();
            return oAuthManager.GetUrlParameters();
        }
    }
}
```

and web.config file has

```
    <add key="Tw-ApiKey" value="your consumer key here"/>
 <add key="Tw-AppSecret" value="your consumer secret here"/>
 <add key="Tw-RedirectUri" value="Twit.aspx"/>
```

in appsetting node.
when I run this app I am getting error ' The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized'.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the string that GetUrlParameters() produces?

Comment: GetUrlParameters()  only giving error ' The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized'.

Comment: I have refered from https://twitteroauth.codeplex.com/

Comment: Can you confirm that you have replaced the values of tw-apikey, tw-appsecret and tw-redirecturi with the ACTUAL values from your Twitter developer account?

Comment: Yes I have replaced that values from Twitter Developer account

Comment: you can check sccen shhot my oauth setting in twitter application http://imageshack.com/scaled/large/203/hmdi.png

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the source of the TwitterOAuth library you are using and traced the web requests using Fiddler, and I'm not convinced it is producing the correct signature.

Firstly the library will send a request to http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token and it produces a signature based on this url. However this request gets redirected to https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token and the signature will not be valid for the new url.

I would try a different library such as those suggested [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).